# None worked - Error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net

I started getting error:
Error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0

Visual Studio Version:
[image]

I have followed lot of posts about:

- Updating Visual studio >> I am using latest
- updating .net >> done
- no MSBuildPath env variable
- no global.json set

none of the solutions worked.

'dotnet info outout'
[image]

Any help

Comment: "Updating .NET >> done" - you mean you've installed the [.NET 6.0 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)? What is the result of `dotnet --list-sdks`?

Comment: Can you please add the output you get when you execute `dotnet --info` in the command line?

Comment: And can you please specify what operating system you are using?

Comment: Did you try `dotnet --version`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to [Announcing .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6/#support):

> .NET 6 is supported with **Visual Studio 2022** and Visual Studio 2022 for Mac. It is **not supported with Visual Studio 2019**, Visual Studio for Mac 8, or MSBuild 16. If you want to use .NET 6, you will need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2022 (which is also now 64-bit).

If you want to use .NET 6 you will need to update to Visual Studio 2022, as it is not supported in Visual Studio 2019.

In [this Developer Community issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2019-support-net-6/1650171), Microsoft have stated:

> We have no plans to support .NET 6 in earlier versions of VS. The general reason is that we add features to VS in order to support newer features in the runtime, languages, and libraries. It’s not practical to backport those.

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts on this. I have downloaded VS 2022 and its working fine now.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio for Mac 2022 17.4 and I cannot get around this error. I have a global.json clearly specifying 6.0.400 as the sdk version, yet building with visual studio outputs "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.408/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(141,5) The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower"...

The output of dotnet --version is 6.0.400, and the global.json is "sdk": { "version": "6.0.400" }, and the TargetFramework is set to net6.0, so why is visual studio trying to use 5.0.408?

Comment: @whendon I too am getting this issue. Did you manage to find a solution to this?